# Explanation of a joke on abelian groups (grapes).

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, definition

Q: What's purple and commutes? A: An Abelian grape.

Q: What is lavender and commutes? A: An Abelian semigrape.

Q: What's purple, commutes, and is worshipped by a limited number of people? A: A finitely-venerated Abelian grape.

Q: What's nutritious and commutes? A: An Abelian soup

I think the first one is because Abelian implies commutativity and group sounds like grape. The second one is because lavender is not really purple so it is a semi-group, not necessarily a group. The third one is a play on "finitely generated". I don't understand the last one.

Am I missing anything?

Thank you and regards.

Comment: you got the first one. the point of the second joke is that a not-quite-ripe grape might be a little lighter than purple and so it would be reasonable to call such a thing a semigrape. the third joke you already get. the last joke is isomorphic to the first joke.

Comment: Oh, I can see the isomorphism clearly now. Thank you!

Comment: Nice one. I've also heard the one about bananach spaces for analysis. I wonder if we can get all of mathematics into one large fruit basket.

Comment: Anybody care to explain what is the original joke is? Why purple, and why grapes? Is it a twist of a common phrase in English, or is it intended to be completely random?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know the last one is just because "soup" sounds like "group." You're spot on on the first three.

I think these four jokes, as someone who has heard their punch lines a bit too many times, are the epitome of bad math jokes.

The only reason people find them funny is because it uses the word Abelian, so in that way it's kind of an inside joke because most people not involved in mathematics wouldn't know what that means.

The most egregious is the second joke. It only works because of the set up of the first! In what context does the thought process "lavender is not that purple-ish, so it's only a semi-grape" (what?) make any sense?!